# How to switch on the property of generic object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type where an attribute's type is generic.

I want to switch on the property to infer the type of the generic value.

Here is the code I did to achieve this. I thought is would work as the compiler should have all the information necessary to infer the type. Apparently not, as the compiler throws an error.

```js
type Foo<T> = {
    value: T
}

type A = { type: 'a', data: number }
type B = { type: 'b', data: string }
type AB = A | B

function doStuff(foo: Foo<AB>) {
    switch(foo.value.type) {
        case 'a': {
            // here TS knows that foo.value is an `A`, why isnt foo a Foo<A> ?
            return doStuffA(foo) // Error (1) on foo
        }
        case 'b': {
            return doStuffB(foo) // Error(2) also on foo
        }
    }
}

function doStuffA(foo: Foo<A>) {
    // ...
}

function doStuffB(foo: Foo<B>) {
    // ...
}
```

And the errors :

```
(Error 1)
Argument of type 'Foo<AB>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo<A>'.
  Type 'AB' is not assignable to type 'A'.
    Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'A'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.

(Error 2)
Argument of type 'Foo<AB>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo<B>'.
  Type 'AB' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
```

Is this a restriction of Typescript ? Or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928920/typescript-narrowing-of-keys-in-objects-when-passed-to-function

Comment: Factory pattern do not solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben Wainwright in the comments, I found the solution.

I needed to create functions that refine the type of `Foo<T>`.

```js
type Foo<T> = {
    value: T
}

type A = { type: 'a', data: number }
type B = { type: 'b', data: string }
type AB = A | B

// here, isA tells the TS compiler that foo is indeed a Foo<A>
function isA(foo: Foo<AB>): foo is Foo<A> {
    return foo.value.type === 'a'
}

// same here for Foo<B>
function isB(foo: Foo<AB>): foo is Foo<B> {
    return foo.value.type === 'b'
}

function doStuff(foo: Foo<AB>) {
    if(isA(foo)) {
        // it works ! here TS recognise foo as Foo<A>
        return doStuffA(foo)
    } else if(isB(foo)) {
        // same here, TS knows that foo is a Foo<B>
        return doStuffB(foo)
    }
}

function doStuffA(foo: Foo<A>) {
    // ...
}

function doStuffB(foo: Foo<B>) {
    // ...
}
```