# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' when not using an intermediate const

Tags: typescript

I have [this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmBhAhgGwwITcA1jALwwAUyEEaA5kjAFxxQBOAlmNQJREB8A3gCgYwmKEggMSAHQYQ1ckko0knAQF8BAqAE8ADnQCy2gCp66JQSJgB3ABYgGTNhwA0QkcEwYARnnwB+RwUlWkdoZy5eADcQVgATNw0hAHpkmABlRDoAMwBXMGAoVnAYKAdaWDQYATFoGAqAeW8AK2IyTkcjU31ifndhZiQoXOYwGEsrETsHRgAidGYJWf6YNQBudQ2a8DqADzbGltJOLdZs0l2pTyxfAk4J4Uvrnz9SWd3Zk-VNWtg4tCgVUYXTMAG0ALptUFWFZ8SZTez0WYAQQwrGASFmVjUbiscPhNkRs2wIG8sxcBNEXlu+Ho8GQ6CwuAI2IE4K2qRgADkHOwoEhmMg4qwAXRfgJsiBmKRJLBWEQAAxrGCsAA8-0BMiQHCgtjWrAA1Ab7porLUJNJZPINWhQaxwVJpl8YVYzqQbXaHc8aR0HpMPfartTXgHIQaYFjvX5PhtWUlOXyBUKRfzRDtYJLmKVbHRSc0kIVqpmZUMVYrlWqbVqdXrDca-b8YAhtE1WiRQ7GPDsLTI5OQWy1HfZnV3ILAoyySM3W0Gbn5O8I3RP8L6VmbgwR+62YOHIxv8DGVhp42lE4KkMLRWmxzBM9mxfuJVKS3Lyyr1QC0NXqLr9UaTSs5qSL21qfp6Q4gCOwiNsubShrOLwEAuKrnMuq6Usu7pgfaO4RlSc4EIecZAA):

```
const someCallBack = (message : string)=>{
    console.log(message)
}

type MyType = {
    who : string,
    callback? : (message : string)=>void,
}

 // Some function to get a 
const getObj = () : MyType =>{
    return {
        who : "Carol"
    };
};

const x = getObj();

if(x.callback){
    x.callback("x");
}

const data : MyType[] = [    
    {        who:"Alice"    },
    {        who:"Bob",        callback:someCallBack    }
];

// No intermediate const
for(let i=0; i<data.length;i++){

    console.log(data[i].who);
    
    if(data[i].callback) {
        data[i].callback(data[i] + " callback");
    }
}

// intermediate const for the object 
for(let i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    const myObj = data[i];
    console.log(myObj.who);
    const callback = myObj.callback;
    if(callback) {
        callback(myObj + " callback");
    }
}

// intermediate const for the callback
for(let i=0; i<data.length;i++){

    console.log(data[i].who);
    const callback = data[i].callback;
    if(callback) {
        callback(data[i] + " callback");
    }
}
```

It fails to compile in the first attempt to loop : `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`

But as soon as I introduce a local for either the object from the loop, or the callback itself, it compiles (2nd and 3rd loops).

The question is : **why?** What's the difference?

Here's the TS playground export:

**Output**

```
"use strict";
const someCallBack = (message) => {
    console.log(message);
};
// Some function to get a 
const getObj = () => {
    return {
        who: "Carol"
    };
};
const x = getObj();
if (x.callback) {
    x.callback("x");
}
const data = [
    { who: "Alice" },
    { who: "Bob", callback: someCallBack }
];
// No intermediate const
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].who);
    if (data[i].callback) {
        data[i].callback(data[i] + " callback");
    }
}
// intermediate const for the object 
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const myObj = data[i];
    console.log(myObj.who);
    const callback = myObj.callback;
    if (callback) {
        callback(myObj + " callback");
    }
}
// intermediate const for the callback
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].who);
    const callback = data[i].callback;
    if (callback) {
        callback(data[i] + " callback");
    }
}
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmBhAhgGwwITcA1jALwwAUyEEaA5kjAFxxQBOAlmNQJREB8A3gCgYwmKEggMSAHQYQ1ckko0knAQF8BAqAE8ADnQCy2gCp66JQSJgB3ABYgGTNhwA0QkcEwYARnnwB+RwUlWkdoZy5eADcQVgATNw0hAHpkmABlRDoAMwBXMGAoVnAYKAdaWDQYATFoGAqAeW8AK2IyTkcjU31ifndhZiQoXOYwGEsrETsHRgAidGYJWf6YNQBudQ2a8DqADzbGltJOLdZs0l2pTyxfAk4J4Uvrnz9SWd3Zk-VNWtg4tCgVUYXTMAG0ALptUFWFZ8SZTez0WYAQQwrGASFmVjUbiscPhNkRs2wIG8sxcBNEXlu+Ho8GQ6CwuAI2IE4K2qRgADkHOwoEhmMg4qwAXRfgJsiBmKRJLBWEQAAxrGCsAA8-0BMiQHCgtjWrAA1Ab7porLUJNJZPINWhQaxwVJpl8YVYzqQbXaHc8aR0HpMPfartTXgHIQaYFjvX5PhtWUlOXyBUKRfzRDtYJLmKVbHRSc0kIVqpmZUMVYrlWqbVqdXrDca-b8YAhtE1WiRQ7GPDsLTI5OQWy1HfZnV3ILAoyySM3W0Gbn5O8I3RP8L6VmbgwR+62YOHIxv8DGVhp42lE4KkMLRWmxzBM9mxfuJVKS3Lyyr1QC0NXqLr9UaTSs5qSL21qfp6Q4gCOwiNsubShrOLwEAuKrnMuq6Usu7pgfaO4RlSc4EIecZAA)

Comment: Because `if(data[i].callback)` doesn't [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `data[i]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript narrowing of keys in objects when passed to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928920/typescript-narrowing-of-keys-in-objects-when-passed-to-function)