# Type-narrowed `let` variable reverts to its original type when passed to a closure

Tags: typescript

In the following code snippet, why does `foobar` revert to being of type `Foobar` when it is referenced from the function passed to `filter`?

```js
type Foo = { type: "foo"; foo: number };
type Bar = { type: "bar"; bar: number };
type Foobar = Foo | Bar;

const foobars: Foobar[] = [
  { type: "foo", foo: 42 },
  { type: "bar", bar: 43 },
];

const numbers = [40, 41, 42, 43, 44];

function logFoo(foo: Foo) {
  console.log(foo.foo);
}

for (let foobar of foobars) {
  if (foobar.type === "foo") {
    console.log(foobar.foo); // foobar is Foo
    logFoo(foobar); // OK
    console.log(numbers.filter(x => x < foobar.foo)); // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Foobar'
  }
}
```

If you change `let foobar of foobars` to `const foobar of foobars` the type error goes away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript narrowing of keys in objects when passed to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928920/typescript-narrowing-of-keys-in-objects-when-passed-to-function)

Comment: @Quentin no, that's about whether type narrowing works in the first place. `foobar` is initially narrowed to `Foo` but loses its identity when referenced from the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in a hurry, the answer is to use `const`.

```
for (const foobar of foobars) {
  if (foobar.type === "foo") {
    console.log(foobar.foo); // fb is Foo
    logFoo(foobar); // OK
    console.log(numbers.filter(x => x < foobar.foo)); // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Foobar'
  }
}
```

A `const` (or 'final', as Java calls it) variable will never be reassigned. That gives us some very strong guarantees. Inside the `if` statement, we *know* absolutely that the value `foobar` has type `Foo`. And since it will never be reassigned, we also know that inside of any closures within the `if` statement. You get the behavior you're expecting.

Now consider `let`.

```
for (let foobar of foobars) {
  if (foobar.type === "foo") {
    console.log(foobar.foo); // fb is Foo
    logFoo(foobar); // OK
    console.log(numbers.filter(x => x < foobar.foo)); // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Foobar'
  }
}
```

A `let`-bound variable can change. TypeScript is smart enough to see that, inside the `if` statement, it hasn't changed. But when it's passed to a closure, that closure could be called from anywhere else in the code. If someone were to come along and assign a new value to this variable somewhere unrelated in the code, then the closure's type safety would break. So the closure makes the coarsest and safest guarantee it can, which is that the `let`-bound variable is of its original type.

In this *particular* example, it's theoretically possible that TypeScript could reason about the fact that our `foobar` is never assigned to at all. After all, its scope is limited to the inside of a `for` loop, and there are no such assignment statements in there. But rather than get that far into the weeds (the scope of a variable could be an entire file, after all, or in the case of instance variables could be multiple files), TypeScript decides to just be conservative.

Note that if you *do* intend to modify the variable later but want to capture its *particular* value at a moment, rather than the variable itself, you can always make a *new* `const`-bound variable to do so.

```
for (let foobar of foobars) {
  if (foobar.type === "foo") {
    const newFoobar = foobar;
    console.log(numbers.filter(x => x < newFoobar.foo)); // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Foobar'
  }
}
```

At the moment `newFoobar` is created, `foobar` has type `Foo`. And `newFoobar` is a `const`, so it will *always* have type `Foo`. Nothing can change that fact beyond this point, so it's safe to capture `newFoobar` (as type `Foo`) inside of a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Silvio's answer is correct but does not fix your code as you might want to use `Bar` in your loop (as mentionned, using `const` will result in `foobar` being a `Foo`).
Therefore i would recommand to use a `forEach` (or a `for in` using `let`) on foobars like

```js
foobars.forEach((foobar: Foobar) => {
    if (foobar.type === "foo") {
      const myFoo: Foo = <Foo> foobar;
      logFoo(myFoo); // OK
      console.log(numbers.filter(x => x < myFoo.foo));
    } else if (foobar.type === "bar") {
      const myBar: Bar = <Bar> foobar;
      console.log(numbers.filter(x => x > myBar.bar));
    }
});
```

Comment: If you use `forEach` you don't need to alias `myFoo` and `myBar`: `foobar` is the expected type everywhere, even though you could reassign it in the same way you could a `let` variable.

Comment: @blisco you might not want to use `bar.foo` in a bar case, which typescript will allow since foobar is a `foobar`